# Charset issue of toPdf method of Blob object in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I need to print out Turkish characters like "ş","ç","ü" etc. in the pdf document.
I am using the following code.

```
global class InvoicePDFGenerator {

    public static final String FORM_HTML_START = '<HTML><BODY>';
    public static final String FORM_HTML_END = '</BODY></HTML>';

    webservice static void generateInvoicePDF(String invoiceId){
        OppoInvoice__c invoice= [SELECT Id,Account_Name__c FROM OppoInvoice__c WHERE Id=:invoiceId];
        String pdfContent = '';
        try {
            pdfContent = '<html><head><meta http-equiv=content-type content=text/html;charset=iso-8859-9></meta></head><body>';

            pdfContent = pdfContent + '<P>' + invoice.Account_Name__c+ '</P>';
            pdfContent = pdfContent + FORM_HTML_END;
        }catch(Exception e){
            pdfContent = '' + FORM_HTML_START;
            pdfContent = pdfContent + '<P>THERE WAS AN ERROR GENERATING PDF: ' + e.getMessage() + '</P>';
            pdfContent = pdfContent + FORM_HTML_END;
        }

        Attachment attachmentPDF = new Attachment();
        attachmentPDF.parentId = invoice.Id;
        attachmentPDF.Name = 'Invoice.pdf';
        attachmentPDF.body = Blob.toPDF(pdfContent); //This creates the PDF content
        insert attachmentPDF;

    }
}
```

I think the problem caused by from the `attachmentPDF.body = Blob.toPDF(pdfContent)` line. Do you have any idea about this issue?

Comment: What happens?  I assume that Salesforce uses UTF-8 in its strings.  Have you tried leaving out the `META` tag that tries to set `charset=iso-8859-9`?

Comment: I also tried to UTF-8 but result did not change. The code is working properly but turkish characters don't appear. For example, If value of pdfContent variable is 'abcşidça', output of pdf document is 'abcida'.

How is it written a meta tag that without? Can you show me an example?

Comment: (1) Can you post a version of the code that does not use the query?  In other words, can you push a string constant with the Turkish characters into pdfContent.   This would allow others (like me) to try out the Blob.toPDF() with different conditions.  (2) Can you create an html file with these same Turkish characters and verify that this file works in a browser.

Comment: This is code that without query.

`global class AccountPDFGenerator{
 webservice static void generateInvoicePDF(String accountId){
//Account account = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Account WHERE Id=:accountId];
  String pdfContent = 'öçşğüıÖÇŞĞÜİ';
  Attachment attachmentPDF = new Attachment();
  attachmentPDF.parentId = accountId;
  attachmentPDF.Name = 'Invoice.pdf';
//attachmentPDF.body= Blob.valueOf(pdfContent);
  attachmentPDF.body = Blob.toPDF(pdfContent); //This creates the PDF content
  insert attachmentPDF;
 } 
}`

Answer (score 0):

This could be a limitation of the `Blob.toPDF` method that you should report to Salesforce.

The closest solution I could come up with was to use the `escapeHtml4()` method on each string, but that only covers a subset of character entities.  It converts your example string, `'abcşidça'` to `'abcşid&ccedil;a'`.

On the off chance the `meta` tag is affecting the output, you could try starting the HTML with just `<html><body>` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I push a string constant with the Turkish characters into pdfContent. Output is 'öçüÖÇÜ'
for input value that is 'öçşğüıÖÇŞĞÜİ'.

This is code that without query.

```
global class AccountPDFGenerator
{

    webservice static void generateInvoicePDF(String accountId)
    {
//     Account account = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Account WHERE Id=:accountId];

        String accId = accountId;

        String pdfContent = '';
        try
        {
            pdfContent = '<html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-9"></meta></head><body>';           
            pdfContent = pdfContent + '<p style="color:red">' + 'öçşğüıÖÇŞĞÜİ' + '</p>';
            pdfContent = pdfContent + '</body></html>';
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            pdfContent = pdfContent + '<P>THERE WAS AN ERROR GENERATING PDF: ' + e.getMessage() + '</P>';
        }
        pdfContent = 'öçşğüıÖÇŞĞÜİ'; 

        Attachment attachmentPDF = new Attachment();
        attachmentPDF.parentId = accId;
        attachmentPDF.Name = 'Invoice.pdf';
//     attachmentPDF.body= Blob.valueOf(pdfContent);
        attachmentPDF.body = Blob.toPDF(pdfContent); //This creates the PDF content
        insert attachmentPDF;

    } 

}
```

This is created javascript code for custom button where Setup>Customize>Account>Buttons and Links

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/apex.js")}
sforce.apex.execute("AccountPDFGenerator","generateInvoicePDF", {id:"{!Account.Id}"});
window.alert("Account Id is sent." );
```

And this is html file content

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv=content-type content=text/html;charset=iso-8859-9></meta></head><body><p>öçşğüıÖÇŞĞÜİ</p></body></html>
```